# Operators in Python 3x

Tags: python

```
-10 // 3 = -4

 10 // -3 = -4

-10 % 3 = 2

 10 % -3 = -2
```

I don't get the logic of these operations.

```
10 // 3 = 3, but -10 // 3 = -4
```

which I cant make sense of.

Please, explain.

Comment: [From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations): The floor division and modulo operators are connected by the following identity: `x == (x//y)*y + (x%y)`

Comment: http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html

Answer (score 1):

This is Because python rounds down. 3.33333 rounded down is 3, wheras -3.33333 rounded down is -4. If you want it to round up, do floating point division, then convert the float to an int.

Answer (score 1):

The operator `//` is the *floor division operator*.

The result of `-10/3` is `-3.3333`. Then, the result of `-10//3` will be rounded to the next integer (lower than the result), so the result will be `-4`.

Comment: What about % operator with negative integers?

Comment: It's not integer division, it's [floor division](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/), and that name pretty much explains it all.